# Not starting debugging after putting <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false"/> in webconfig

Tags: asp.net, iis

Not starting debugging after putting `<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false"/>` in webconfig. After commented out this line its working fine.I am using Visual Studio 2008.

While debugging following things are happening,
              debugger icon will be disabled,
              starts building,
              successfully completed,
              Then it stops and enable the debugger icon,

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.enableversionheader.aspx

This article mentions that the version header tells Visual Studio which version of .NET is in use. You only want to change it to false for release builds.